# No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef" Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I can't make migrations because of this issue:

> No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef"

And I've already added package in my `.csproj`

> ItemGroup
>     DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0" ItemGroup
>
> ItemGroup
>       PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.6" 
>       PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.0.2"
>       PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworokCore.Design" Version="2.0.2" 
>     ItemGroup

And I've already installed the Nuget  package.

Comment: Try `dotnet ef`, not `dotnet-ef`.

Comment: Add the full command you are executing to your post